# Where should i call MobileAds.initialize()?

Tags: android, kotlin, admob

I have read https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start?hl=en-US#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk

I need to initialize MobileAds using Code A in order to display AdMob AD.

I have some activities which need to display ADs, do I need to  add code A in my all activities?

And more, why can the AdMob Ad be displayed correctly even if I remove

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID")
```

**Code A**

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    ...
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID")
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: No there is no needed to implement in all activity you have to just implement only on one activity .

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/MobileAds.html#initialize(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)) of `MobileAds.initialize()`:

> This method should be called as early as possible, and **only once per
>   application launch**.

The proper way to do this would be to call it in the `onCreate()` method of the `Application` class.

If you don't have an `Application` class, simply create one, something like this:

```
class YourApp: Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID")
    }
}
```

You have to reference this class in *AndroidManifest.xml*, by setting the `android:name` attribute of the `application` tag:

```
<application
    android:name=".YourApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!-- ... -->

</application>
```

And regarding your question:

> why can the AdMob Ad be displayed correctly even if I remove
>
> ```
> MobileAds.initialize(this, "YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID")
> ```

[Quote](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/kayQ3VZJqkU/QDewNIFpBAAJ) from **Veer Arjun Busani** of the Mobile Ads SDK team:

> The Mobile Ads SDK take a few milliseconds to initialize itself and we
>   now have provided this method to call it way before you even call your
>   first ad. Once that is done, there would not be any added load time
>   for your first request. If you do not call this, then your very first
>   AdRequest would take a few milliseconds more as it first needs to
>   initialize itself.

So basically if you do not call `MobileAds.initialize()`, then the first `AdRequest` will call it implicitly.

Comment: I would rather have that few milliseconds on loading my first ad than on my app booting up :|

Answer (score 2):

`MobileAds.initialize(this, "YOUR-APP-ID")` has deprecated.
 Use the below code instead.

```
import android.app.Application
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds

class MyApp: Application() {

   override fun onCreate() {
       MobileAds.initialize(applicationContext)
       super.onCreate()
   }

}
```

Comment: you didn't include a very important piece of information. You also need to include the meta-data in AndroidManifest.xml as shown as https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/quick-start#update_your_androidmanifestxml

Answer (score 0):

Initializing MobileAds in Aplication context will cause error with InMobi mediation adapter

```
"Adapter Initialization status: Not Ready"
```

Tested with AdMob Test Suite.

Solution is to initialize MobileAds in Activity context.